# failed to find Build Tools revision in Android Studio 3.1.2

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

**Searched a lot, none worked**

I face this error everyday when importing any sample project after upgrading to Android Studio 3 series.

**Case Scenario :**

When i import any project whose `buildToolVersion` is not available in my sdk. Then this error comes. **This error never solves even after changing this version to available version.**

```
failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.0
Install Build Tools 24.0.0 and sync project
```

As solution i changed `buildToolsVersion` in app `build.gradle` and Rebuild project.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
```

**Expected Behaviour**

This error should be gone when i changed `buildToolVersion` as available version. But it's not.

**Tried :**

- Clean project
- Rebuild project
- delete .gradle folder
- delete build folder

**I don't want to install every sdk version so please don't suggest to do so. Also i don't want to update it's version to latest 27 because it is sample module forked, i don't want to work on it further to make it compatible to 27.**

**build.gradle app**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "harshvasoya.gameofcards"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
}
```

**stacktrace**

```
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.addConfigurationFailure(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:79)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:74)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:540)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:93)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$2.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:124)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:121)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.getBuildAnalysis(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:88)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.configure(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:107)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:237)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to find Build Tools revision 24.0.0
    at com.android.builder.sdk.DefaultSdkLoader.getTargetInfo(DefaultSdkLoader.java:87)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.SdkHandler.initTarget(SdkHandler.java:126)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.ensureTargetSetup(BasePlugin.java:684)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.createAndroidTasks(BasePlugin.java:621)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:571)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10$1.call(BasePlugin.java:568)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:567)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$10.execute(BasePlugin.java:564)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:82)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.afterEvaluate(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.notifyAfterEvaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:67)
    ... 57 more
```

Comment: You don't need to install every API version... There's only ever one build tools version in the SDK Manager

Comment: Did you read question before suggesting bro

Comment: Yes I did... I said you **do not** need to install every API version, which you seem to think you do

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, i know this, before updating AS i had hardly 2-3 build version, but new AS shows error even i changed it in gradle. and clean rebuild not works. i resolved this error by restarting AS.

Comment: "Build Tools revision 24.0.0" simply doesn't exist. At least not since 2016... Not sure how that's an IDE bug, as you say

Comment: I think i don't know how to explain, i said it is IDE bug because, this issue still persist after changing it. Do you think IDE should show me error of 24.0.0 if this actually does not exist in my whole project?

Comment: You would get the same error trying to build your project on the command line, outside of Android Studio, if that build tool version didn't exist, as the error says. Therefore, it cannot possibly be a bug in the IDE

Comment: Why are you not getting me dude. I am 4 years experience developer. I know what is IDE issue and what is gradle file issue

Comment: It should not be there if once i changed my version, that's the issue.

Comment: Going through the same problem myself. Despite changing the buildToolsVersion to the correct available one, it keeps telling me the "older" version couldn't be found. Restart of AS didn't work and it's still thinking the older version is specified.

Comment: @PranoyC Try deleting `.idea` and `.gradle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When nothing worked. then i restarted Android studio and it worked.

I did not need to change `targetSdkVersion` and `com.android.support` version.

or

Just reopen that project.

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade your versions

- **compileSdkVersion**
- **buildToolsVersion**

Try with

```
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "harshvasoya.gameofcards"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
}
```

**FYI**

Use **API 24 Level**

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"
```

**and**

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
```

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Restart`** your **IDE**

Comment: @cricket_007 yes sir

Comment: Solution not for me. I dont want to update version because it is an sample module. i dont want to work on it again to make it compatible to latest version 27.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but this is AS bug, project successfully compiled after restarting AS

Comment: Did this helped. I will post an answer, i can give you upvote for suggesting me great things. Because upgrading version and using same versions- both are not solution.

Comment: We can use different versions, this gives warning but not errors. So your answer can be used to down warn. I expected an solution for bug of AS